# Fastest way to retrieve records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

I need to retrieve columns from two tables and I have used an INNER JOIN. But its consuming lot of time during loading the page. Is there any better and faster way to achieve the same?

> Select P.Col1, P.Col2, P.Col3, P.Col4, P.Col5, C.Col1, C.Col2, C.Col3 from Pyalers P inner join Customers C on C.Col1 = P.Col1 where P.Col2 = 5

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your DDL, there's no way to say.

But conceptually this is ok, just be sure you have proper indexs sets.

For instance: (is your table name really 'Pyalers'? Assuming 'players')

```
CREATE INDEX idx_players ON `players` (col1);
CREATE INDEX idx_customers ON `customers` (col1);
```

use the columns you need for joinning the 2 tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Sorry, I never used index in entire life. Gosh, never realized. A quick link so that I can work on the same..?

Comment: you added the index on players, but twice :-) You have to add the same but on the customers table as well (on the column of customers that you are using for the join)
You also need to `DROP INDEX playersID_2 ON players`, which is redundant and potentially adding up overhead.

Comment: Yap, Got it now. I fixed the index on Players and also added index in Customer. But the column from Customer table which I using for join is not the primary key also may not be an unique. Will it be a problem.?

Comment: not at all, you don't have to create a unique index, a normal index (like the one i mentionned in the queries above) is enough.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful and quick. I hope this will solve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: keep me posted! What about the performances now? If you have a lot of players it could be interesting to add an index on the players.col2 column as well

Comment: Ya, I am going through some articles on indexing. Once I understand the concept of Indexing, well I will do as it is necessary. Thanks for all the helpful posts. Now I can see real performance difference. Between, once we enable indexing on existing table, how long it takes for indexing a huge table of say 20000 Rows.?

Comment: to create the index you mean? It depends on the size of the column mainly, so let's say for a basic ID field, a few secondes, minutes if your server is overwhelmed...

Comment: Hmmn. Thanks again, that was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the right way, but if you don't have indexes on your tables on the correct columns, it's not going to be very fast for tables of any size.  Do Pyalers.col1 and Customers.col1 both have indexes on them?

Show us how the tables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your table has the needed indexes... as a "thumb rule", every field which is used for search (`WHERE`) or data joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`) should be indexed.

Example: If you are creating a table, you can add your indexes at that time (notice that your tables should always have a primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
myId int unsigned not null,
someField varchar(50),
primary key (myId),
index someIdx(someField)
);
```

If your table already exists, and you want to add indexes, you need to use the `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD INDEX someIdx(someField),
ADD PRIMARY KEY (myId);
```

Rules:

1. To define an index you most provide a unique name for it, and specify the fields included in the index: `INDEX myIndex(field1, field2, ...)`
2. There are different types of indexes: `PRIMARY KEY` is used for primary keys (that's obvious, huh?); `INDEX` is an 'ordinary index', just used to speed up search and join operations; `UNIQUE INDEX` is an index that prevents duplicate values.

Recomendations:

- Whenever you can, index all numeric and date fields that are relevant (ids, birth date, etc.). Avoid creating indexes on fields that contain 'double' values.
- Don't abuse of indexes, because abuse can create very large index files.

Tips:

- If you want to see how your query will be executed, you can use the `EXPLAIN` statement:

  EXPLAIN SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.myId = b.otherId

This instruction will show you the execution plan of the query. If in the last column you see 'file sort' or 'using temporary', you may (just may) need aditional indexes (notice that if you use `GROUP BY` you will almost always get the 'using temporary' message)

Hope this help you

Comment: Awesome.. that was quite a useful one. Love it.